# VB Inequality Operator False Result

Tags: operator-keyword, inequality

I have some problems with the inequality operators.

Consider the code below:

```
If a >= 0.00000001 Then
            ' action statement
End If
```

a variable is a Single and a = 0.00000001.

When I run the if condition using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express, the Immediate Windows says it is false. I have inserted a screenshot for your reference. 
[Screenshot](http://s9.postimg.org/fs6dmzyj3/diff.png)

Do you know what is the root cause of this issue and how do I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating-point math is not exact.  It's an approximation.

There's more to it here: http://floating-point-gui.de/